# How do I upgrade Magento 1.9.0.1 to latest version

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, installation

When I use Magento Connect Manager and installed mage_all_latest, in the middle of installation it says can't open the folder: **downloader/.cache/..... renderer** and **downloader/.cache/..... conf.**

Can someone help me how to resolve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Cause :-**

> The reason is that function working with archives passing non-ASCII
>   characters in the filename and the filename cannot be created simply
>   due to filesystem restrictions on filenames.

**The simple fix can be just patch :-**

[The fix has been applied already for all our new installations.](https://kb.magenting.com/content/22/70/en/magento-connect-error-can%E2%80%99t-write-to-file-downloader-cache-community.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a quick, proper and easy way to upgrade Magento 2 website version to latest one.

NOTE: There are many ways to upgrade Magento version, but I recommend this way to everyone.

Important: Take backup of database and files before follow below steps.

Follow below steps to upgrade any magento 2 website from current to latest Magento version..

Step 1: php bin/magento maintenance:enable

Step 2: composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.1 --no-update

NOTE: Change 2.3.1 in above line to version in which you want to upgrade. Here i am upgrading to 2.3.1

Step 3: composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update

Step 4: composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update

Step 5: Update autoload

"autoload": {

```
"psr-4": {

    "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",

    "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",

    "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",

    "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"

},

...
```

}

Step 6: composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-community-edition=2.3.1 temp_dir --no-install
NOTE: Change 2.3.1 in above line to version in which you want to upgrade. Here i am upgrading to 2.3.1

Step 7:

rm -rf update

mkdir update

mv temp_dir/update update

rm -rf temp_dir

Step 8: composer update

Step 9: redis-cli -s /var/run/redis-multi-a0a405e6.redis/redis.sock FLUSHALL
NOTE: Only required some time: (Below command is different based on server, Please ask to hosting support for clear radis cache. Above is working for nexcess clould hosting)

Step 10:

bin/magento cache:clean

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/page_cache/*

rm -rf generated/code/*

Step 11: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Step 12: php bin/magento maintenance:disable

I have prepared above all steps from this doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html Please refer this doc to know in detail about each steps.